# How can I keep the original :focus element with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

So, I have an `<input>` element that has the `:focus` attribute from CSS on it.

**CSS**

```
#my_input {
border: 1px solid black;
}

#my_input:focus {
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

This input is for a login form. If a user gets something wrong for a form, like entering less then the min characters, then the input form has a border of red. Once the error is fixed, I want the border to go back to normal. The border is turned back to normal, but now the :focus element from CSS doesn't work.

*Once the user fixes the errors*

**JS**

```
$("#my_input").css("border", "1px solid black");
```

**How do you fix this problem?**

Comment: Please remember to follow our ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy when posting anything here, including comments. There's never a good reason to be rude here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `$("#my_input").css("border", "1px solid black");`, you're overwriting the CSS as you're adding that style directly to the element. Instead, use `$("#my_input").css("border", "");` which will then force `#my_input` to use your original CSS styling.

As a quick tip, it would instead be better to do the following:

**CSS**

```
#my_input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#my_input:focus {
  border-color: green;
}

#my_input.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Then in your **JS**, to *highlight the error:*

```
$("#my_input").addClass('error');
```

And then to *remove the error highlight:*

```
$("#my_input").removeClass('error');
```

Comment: It's a single attribute. You might as well make it all JS rather than creating two whole new classes for a single rule each. Something like ``.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid red');`` and alter it with the validation.

Comment: It's only one extra class, not two, and it makes the JS a lot more readable. And true it's only one attribute for now, doesn't mean there won't be more - a login form rarely has just one input. I suppose it's simply personal preference. I was just recommending a method that would surely come in handy for anyone looking to progress in using CSS with JS.

Comment: Ah, I see. jQuery allows the ability to remove a class and keep the animation, whereas pure JS simply allows you to switch between two, which you must do for it to animate.